# SPheno-4.0.5 make command not running (MacOS)

Tags: macos, makefile, fortran, gnu-make, gfortran

In my work I am using a Fortran based program called SPheno. Having SPheno-4.0.4 installed, I tried to install the new version SPheno-4.0.5, however, when selecting `F90 = gfortran` in the Makefile, just as I did on my working SPheno-4.0.4 version, it returns me the following error:

```
cd src ; /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make F90=gfortran version=400.00
gfortran -c -O -J../include -I../include  -DGENERATIONMIXING  -DONLYDOUBLE Control.F90
ar  ../lib/libSPheno.a Control.o
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ar: illegal option -- .
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-TLsv] archive file ...
    ar -m [-abiTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -p [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -q [-cTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-cuTLsv] archive file ...
    ar -r [-abciuTLsv] position archive file ...
    ar -t [-TLsv] archive [file ...]
    ar -x [-ouTLsv] archive [file ...]
make[1]: *** [../lib/libSPheno.a(Control.o)] Error 1
make: *** [bin/SPheno] Error 2
```

What does this error even mean, and what do I have to change? I even tried to copy/paste the Makefile from SPheno-4.0.4, just to check.

In case it matters, when running the command `gfortran -v` it returns me:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/11.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0/lib/gcc/11 --disable-nls --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,d --program-suffix=-11 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-zstd=/usr/local/opt/zstd --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 11.2.0' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --enable-libphobos --build=x86_64-apple-darwin19 --with-system-zlib --disable-multilib --with-native-system-header-dir=/usr/include --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 11.2.0)
```

The Makefile at play is the following:

```
# please put here your preferred F95/F2003 compiler
# the options in src/Makefile have been put for the
# cases NAG's nagfor, gfortran, g95, Lahey's lf95 and Intels ifort
# Please uncomment the corresponding line
# F90 = nagfor
 F90 = gfortran
# F90 = g95
# F90 = lf95
# F90 = ifort
Model = src
version = 400.00
bin/SPheno:
    cd ${Model} ; ${MAKE} F90=${F90} version=${version}
clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ */*.o */*~
cleanall:
    rm -f bin/SPheno lib/*.a *.o *~ */*.o */*~ include/*
.PHONY: bin/SPheno clean cleanall
```

Comment: From what you have given above it seems the problem has nothing to do with gfortran, but rather with ar which you need to supply an extra option to to specify what you want to do - my guess is you need -r. Quite how you do this I can't say, you haven't provided enough information.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! What information could I provide to make the problem clearer? I don't understand much of the returned errors, so I don't know what to show, exactly. I also tried using the command ``make -r`` but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output means that make invoked this command:

```
ar  ../lib/libSPheno.a Control.o
```

which runs the `ar` (archive) program and apparently wants to put the `Control.o` object into the `../lib/libSPheno.a` archive.  However, that command line is incorrect because there's supposed to be an option after the `ar` which tells it what operation to perform.  This output:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ar: illegal option -- .
usage:  ar -d [-TLsv] archive file ...
  ...
```

is printed by the `ar` program telling you that your invocation is invalid.

Then this line:

```
make[1]: *** [../lib/libSPheno.a(Control.o)] Error 1
```

is `make` telling you that the command it invoked (`ar`) to build the target `../lib/libSPheno.a(Control.o)` failed, with error code 1.

Somewhere in the makefile you need to find the rule that is telling make to run the `ar` program.  We can't tell you where it is; unfortunately your version of make is too old (Apple is notorious for shipping outdated and buggy versions of GNU utilities): newer versions would give you the line number of the rule in the makefile that failed.

Most likely the rule will refer to the variable `$(AR)` and maybe `$(ARFLAGS)` or something.

Comment: Thank you very much for breaking this message down in such an understandable manner! In the meanwhile I also tried to run ``make CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-11``so that it uses the installation from brew (as was mentioned in some other posts), but it returned the same error message. When opening the Makefile I don't see any option related to ar. I will post the Makefile in an edit.

Comment: That's because you're looking in the wrong file.  In your makefile you can see that it actually runs make in a subdirectory: `cd ${Model} ; ${MAKE} F90=${F90} version=${version}`.  The `${Model}` variable is `src`, which means you need to be looking in the `src/Makefile`.  I suspect that this file is too large to post here, so please look through it and try to find the appropriate rules.

Comment: Thank you very much! Tinkering with the Makefile on that folder did the trick! May I ask how did you knew the ``${Model}`` variable was ``src`` ?

Comment: Because of the line `Model = src` in the makefile you show